# Shell If else with regex

Tags: shell

I am using shell to simple String regex match. Here is my shell

```
#!/bin/sh

MSG="ANK"
PATTERN="([A-Z]{3,5}[-][0-9]{2,5})"

if [ "$MSG" =~ "$PATTERN" ]; then
    echo "MATCHED";
else
    echo "not";
fi
```

It is giving error

abc.sh: 6: [: ANK: unexpected operator

How should I fix this?

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` != `#!/bin/bash` - `[[` and regex matching is available in `bash`, not in 'pure' `sh`.

Comment: at least it should be `[0-9]{....}` , the closing `]` is missing. And this should be checked before you posted.

Comment: And I think it might require `=~` instead of `~=`.

Comment: Updated the code based on comments, still getting error

Comment: As Petesh wrote, you can't use /bin/sh, and you must use `[[`. Also, don't quote the pattern variable: `if [[ $MSG =~ $PATTERN ]]` -- otherwise it's considered plain text not a regex. Doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs

Answer (score 0):

Making the changes proposed by several contributors in the comments yields:

```
#!/bin/bash

MSG="ANK"
PATTERN="([A-Z]{3,5}[-][0-9]{2,5})"

if [[ "$MSG" =~ $PATTERN ]]; then
    echo "MATCHED";
else
    echo "not";
fi
```

Note the change to `bash`, the change to `[[` and removal of the quotation marks around `$PATTERN`.